# Problem with fileChooser. File chooser handling does not work with multiple connections to the same page

Tags: node.js, node-modules, puppeteer

Problem with upload files.

I don't know why this can happen. Maybe not for every site. I don't know why this can happen. Maybe not for every site. I don't know why this can happen. Maybe not for every site.

```
if (config.executable_path === "" || config.executable_path === false) {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: config.chrome_headless,
        args: config.chrome_options,
        defaultViewport: {"width": 1024, "height": 768}
    });
 } else {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: config.chrome_headless,
        args: config.chrome_options,
        executablePath: config.executable_path,
        defaultViewport: {"width": 1024, "height": 768}
    });
 }
```

```
 bot = await this.browser.newPage();
 bot.setViewport({"width": 1024, "height": 768});
 let user_agent = await this.browser.userAgent();
 bot.setUserAgent(user_agent.replace("Headless", ""));
 await this.bot.emulate(iPhone);
 let selector = "span[aria-label=\"New Post\"]";
 await this.bot.waitForSelector(selector, {timeout: 5000});
 await this.utils.sleep(this.utils.random_interval(3, 4));
 var filePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), this.config.assets_path + photo);
 const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([

 this.bot.waitForFileChooser(),

 this.bot.click(selector),

 ]);
 await fileChooser.accept([filePath]);
```

Error: File chooser handling does not work with multiple connections to the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be your browser that doesn't support the fileChooser, 
my old Chromium comes this error and chrome too,
after upgrade to a Chromium 77.0.3844.0 (r674921) or higher.
it works with puppeteer 2.1.0 very well

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running in Chromium.  It should work if you remove the executablePath parameter from the config.

Answer (score 1):

As McD wrote try running in Chromium instead of Chrome. It seems there is an issue with chrome and file upload: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4783